# How can I accept any amount of Arguments in Java as Int, to for example add the numbers?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java code where you can put any amount of numbers when running the code and it will add them all together. I know that with `Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`
I can take 1 int but what if I want to accept as many as the user inputs?

Comment: Loop through all of `args` (e.g. using a `for`-loop), doing the same for each element what you would do for a single argument.

Comment: @maloomeister what type of loop would do that best?

Comment: Use a `for`-loop, with the loop condition being from `0` to `args.length`. Then use the loop index to access the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing the args, if an argument is not an "int" the program replace it with 0:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SumArgs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(element -> {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(element);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }).sum();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: How can I change this so that I print an error message incase something other than an int is given. Like "abc"

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   int result = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(element -> {

    return Integer.parseInt(element);

   }).sum();
   System.out.println(result);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("Error !");
  }
 }

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static void method1(int ... a ){
        for(int num: a){
            System.out.println("num = " + num);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer, as it currently is, does not answer the question. Also, code only answers are usually not overly helpful. Consider adding an explanation / description to your answers in the future.